# RichTextBox shows wrong color when used with LoadFile() and SaveFile() repeatedly

Tags: winforms, file-io, visual-studio-2005, richtextbox, richtext

I'm using VS2005 with VB.net on a Windows XP machine to create a WinForms executable.

Seems I can successfully load text into a RichTextBox, set a color, write a line, and save it.

But later in my code when I repeat those same actions... the red color becomes black instead.

What am I doing wrong here:

```
For i As Int16 = 1 To 2
    rtb.LoadFile("test.txt")
    rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Red : rtbCommands.AppendText("line " & vbCrLf)
    rtb.SaveFile("test.txt")
Next i
```

Shouldn't ALL those lines be red?  Why are some black?

Comment: unused "i" .. and you didn't get color.red from the file ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is months later, but here's my answer:
Unfortunately, I don't think *you* are doing anything wrong. I think it is what Microsoft did wrong in their interface for the RichTextBox control. I find that it is just clunky, awkward, and counter-intuitive. What was happening in your code, is the SelectionColor property sets the color of the currently selected text. Why it colorizes the first word but not the second is a mystery to me as I've not tried to fully understand Microsoft's oddities. But I understand it enuf to know what code you need to use:

```
rtb.SaveFile("test.txt")
For i As Int32 = 1 To 2
    rtb.LoadFile("test.txt")

    Dim oldBeg% = rtb.SelectionStart    ' save original selection
    Dim oldLen% = rtb.SelectionLength ' save original selection
    Dim newBeg% = rtb.TextLength
    rtb.AppendText("line " & vbCrLf)
    Dim newLen% = rtb.TextLength - newBeg
    ' now color the newly added text ...
    rtb.Select(newBeg, newLen) : rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Red
    ' now select the text that was (or was not) selected before text was appended
    rtb.Select(oldBeg, oldLen)

    rtb.SaveFile("test.txt")
Next i
```

one small note: I use an Int32 instead of the Int16 you used because unfortunately, an Int16 is *not* faster in .NET, but is really slower. Not that anything superfast like this simple loop really needs any speed improvement, but the Int32 and UInt32 in .NET are the smallest Int's that don't get converted to a larger Int internally when used in loops like this.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you have to do like this ...

```
rtb.LoadFile("test.txt")
rtb.Select(rtb.TextLength)
rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Red : rtbCommands.AppendText("line " & vbCrLf)
rtb.SaveFile("test.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it makes absolutely no sense... but you have to select all the existing text already in the box.  (The text that you do NOT want to color red.)   Then DO set its SelectionColor to red.  Then do the append.

The results will be correct... as backwards as that sounds.

I have no idea why that works... or why it's necessary.... but you'll never get it to work any other way.  (I've tried countless other "correct" methods.  But they never work.)

Thanks Microsoft!